# Fget's automatically \n after reading a string

Tags: c, pointers, fgets

I have got a really weird issue. After using fgets to read/type a string pointer the next time i want to read a new string from the keyboard the first character automatically becomes \n. How can i avoid/overwrite that ?
I've tried to use

```
if (firstString[strlen(firstString) - 1] == '\n')
        firstString[strlen(firstString) - 1 ] = 0;
```

but it's still not working.
Thanks for help.
Here is my code :

```
void citire_text (char *text , int numar_linii)
 {
    char *text_linie;
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<=numar_linii;i++)
    {
        char *text_linie;
        text_linie = malloc(MAX*sizeof(char));
        fgets(text_linie,MAX,stdin);
        strcat(text,text_linie);

    }
    if (text[strlen(text) - 1] == '\n')
        text[strlen(text) - 1 ] = 0;

}   

void citire_operatie (char *operatie) 
{

    fgets(operatie,MAX+2,stdin);
    printf("%d",*operatie);
    if ((*operatie)=='\n')
        printf("YES");
    else

        printf("NO\n");




}
int main(void) 
{
    char *text,*operatii;
    int numarDeLinii,i;
    scanf("%d",&numarDeLinii);
    text = malloc(MAX*numarDeLinii*sizeof(char));
    operatii = malloc((MAX+2)*sizeof(char)); 
    citire_text(text,numarDeLinii);
    int numar_operatii;
    scanf("%d",&numar_operatii);    
    for(i = 1;i<= numar_operatii;i++)
        citire_operatie(operatii);
    return 0;
}
```

If i set "numar_operatii" to 1 , in the  subprogram citire_operatie fgets won't be even called.

Comment: `fgets` consumes the terminating newline character (i.e. removes it from the stream and adds it to the buffer), so we'd need to see your code to say what exactly is causing the issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `fgets()` will *read* the newline if possible. So removing the potential newline (like you do) would be fine. Either you input more than what `fgets()` reads or you have some `scanf()` calls interleaved with `fgets()` which is causing the problem.

Comment: Eliminate the `\n` with `firstString[strcspn(firstString, "\n")] = 0;`

Comment: Can you please show the declaration of firstSring? And also the output of the execution

Comment: @Michi is not working...

Comment: @eyalm i have just posted the program

Answer (score 1):

Best to not mix `scanf()` functions with `fgets()`.  There is a `'\n'` left-over from when code read `scanf("%d", ...`

Instead of

```
 scanf("%d",&numarDeLinii);
```

Read with `fgets()`

```
char buf[80];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) Handle_EOF();
if (sscanf(buf, scanf("%d",&numarDeLinii) != 1) Handle_Nonnumeric_Input();
```

Or make a simple helper function to read an `int`.  Something like:

```
int Read_int(FILE *istream, const char * prompt, int *dest)  {
  char buf[80];
  while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)) {
    fputs(prompt, stdout);
    fflush(stdout);
    if (sscanf(buffer, "%d", dest) == 1) return 1;
  }
  return EOF;
}

// Usage
if (Read_int(stdin, "Enter lines", &numarDeLinii) != 1) return FAIL;
if (Read_int(stdin, "Enter operations", &numar_operatii) != 1) return FAIL;
```

Comment: it still isn't working properly..

Comment: @Petru Gurita Information like 1) what is the value of `MAX`? 2)  what is the input? 3) describe how it improperly worked.  These would help solve the problem.

Comment: MAX is just a value of 12001 .The input is a number of rows followed by the content on each of them . The problem is that the subprogram citire_operatie doesn't work properly.If numar_operatii =1 , the function fgets() from citire_operatie is not used , the only result being a YES (as if i entered '\n' even if i didn't ).If numar_operatii =2, same happens(automatically prints DA). +get to use fgets() one time .If numar_operatii=3 same problem, can use fgets() two times . And so on.

Comment: @Petru Gurita The `'\n'` observed in "as if i entered '\n' even if i didn't" is the `'\n'` from the previous entry.  In the comment, you _describe_ the input.   Better to append to the post the _true input_. Something like "2<Enter>", "abc<Enter>", "def<Enter>", "3<Enter>", "xyz<Enter>", "aa<Enter>", "bb<Enter>", and indicate in sequence the output observed.  Also do you want `for(i=0;i<numar_linii;i++)` instead of `<=`?

Comment: i taught i could solve the problem if i used < instead of  <=